# I'm confused with this database, should I create more Foreign Keys or more columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating this database about `Movies, Series and Actors`. The `Movies` part is done, but I'm confused with the `Series+Actors` part. My goal is to have 4 tables, 1 of series in general, 1 with the number of seasons and episodes, 1 with the actors info (already connected by foreign key with the movies table).

I've created this tables:

```
SeriesData (
  SerieID int PK,
  SerieName varchar(50),
  SerieDescription text,
  SerieCategory varchar(50),
  SerieYear varchar(4),
  ActorID int FK);

ActorsData (
  ActorID int PK,
  ActorName varchar(50),
  ActorAge varchar(3),
  MoviesParticipated varchar(50))
```

For now its OK, but now comes my confusion.
I need to create 2 more tables right? A seasons and episodes table, since we can't put that type of data in the first table and I need a MoviesParticipated table. How do I do it so that I can get the data of 'How many episodes does every season have?'

This is my current SeasonsEpisodes table, but this will only tell me how many seasons and how many episodes the series has right?

```
SeasonsEpisodes (
  SerieID int PK,
  SerieSeasons int,
  SerieEpisodes int
```

For the MoviesParticipated table would be something like this (My goal is to output each movie/series he participated)?

```
MoviesParticipated (
ActorID int PK
MovieID varchar(50) FK,
SerieID varchar(50) FK)
```

Which Foreign Keys should I create? Should I add more columns?

Comment: "How many episodes does every season have" could be done with `SELECT SerieID, SerieSeaons, COUNT(SerieEpisodes) FROM SeasonsEpisodes GROUP BY SerieID, SerieSeasons` I think. (That's assuming that `SerieSeasons` contains the ID of a specific season.)

Comment: Can you have more than one actor in a series? If so you shouldn't have `ActorId` on `SeriesData` you should create a table in between Actor and Series with has an FK to both ActorId and SeriesId

Comment: @TomHalson I think that's the purpose of the proposed `MoviesParticipated` table. But yes the ActorID would also need removing from the `SeriesData` table at the same time. I'd also point out to Diogo that, depending on the level of detail required, it might actually be desirable to associate an actor which a specific Season or Episode, rather than just a Series.

Comment: Actually Diogo...what's the relationship between Moves and Series? Sounds like we are talking about two different things here...movies don't have seasons or episodes...but TV shows do. Are you trying to implement both concepts in your database? It's a bit unclear what each of your proposed tables is meant to be achieving.

Comment: @ADyson yeah, thats what MoviesParticipated is for, but can I keep MovieID and SerieID in the same table? Will it create any problem? Hmm, for now i guess im only not detailing that much. Im going to keep the actors in the 'Whole serie'. Later I might detail it a bit more

Comment: @ADyson yeah, its 2 different things. Movies and Series have no relationship. Only Actors - Movies and Series - Actors

Comment: The difficulty you'll have if you put both Movie ID and Series ID into the MoviesParticipated table is defining the primary key for that table. Since key fields cannot be null, you can't use either of those fields in the primary key (because one or other of them would always be blank). And because of that you can't guarantee that duplicate entries (i.e. same actor specified twice for one movie or series) would not be created. So far that reason I don't think it's the correct design.

Comment: I can see two possible options here depending how you want to proceed: 1) Merge the Movies and Series tables into one table (maybe called "Media" or something, I dunno), with a "Type" column to indicate if it's a movie or a table. I imagine a lot of the data fields will be similar anyhow. Then you can have a "MediaParticipated" table holding the media item ID  and the actor ID, to represent the relationship. Or.... 2) You create a MoviesParticipated table with MovieID and ActorID, and also a separate SeriesParticipated table with SeriesID and ActorID.

Comment: I can't tell you which is best, it depends how you want to model the real world onto your database. Both are valid from a technical point of view. You have to make a decision about which one best represents the information you want to store in the database.

Comment: Offtopic, but use nvarchar() instead of varchar(), use date of birth instead of age, make FK same type as PK (int).

Comment: @ADyson I think that for me, the second option its the best, because Im doing a MVC website and its easier to manipulate 2 specific tables (at least for me it is)

Comment: I'm not sure that the use of the MVC pattern per se is a valid reason for that...but if you really mean that it suits the way you want to present the data to users then that's a very sensible reason, so go for it.

Comment: @ADyson not that im thinking, will I be able to list all the actors that participate in the serie/movie? And SerieID will have the value of the serie in general, not the specific season

Comment: yes you will be able to list all the actors in any given movie or series easily. For movies: `SELECT m.*, a.* FROM Movie  m INNER JOIN MovieParticipation mp ON mp.MovieID = m.MovieID INNER JOIN Actor a ON a.ActorID = mp.ActorID WHERE m.MovieID = 1`. And the same idea for series.

Comment: 'm' would be MoviesData, 'a' is ActorsData and 'mp' would be MovieParticipation right?

Comment: Yes, those are [table aliases](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) . You can see how I wrote `m`, `a`, and `mp` after the end of the name of each table in the FROM section. This just defines a useful shorthand for the table name when writing the rest of the code. It saves on typing! (And it's also occasionally essential to distinguish the table instances, in cases where you need to join a table to itself)

Comment: Im so sorry, its my first time doing a more complex database (at least for me it is complex), but if im not outputting anything from the table `MoviesParticipated` that means that I have to keep the `MoviesParticipated` column in MoviesData? If so, what is the relationship between that and MoviesParticipated? If not, I output through what column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Since, Actors to Movies/Series participated is [many to many] combination, its efficient to have a seperate table for the mapping.

2) You donot need a reference of Participation on the Actors Table, since ActorsID is referred in the Participation table

you can refer the below table structures:

```
--Series Table
SeriesData (
SeriesID int PK,
SeriesName varchar(50),
SeriesDescription text,
SeriesCategory varchar(50),
SeriesYear varchar(4));

--Actors Table
ActorsData (
ActorID int PK,
ActorName varchar(50),
ActorAge varchar(3))

--SeasonsnEpisodes
SeasonsEpisodes (
SeasonsEpisodesId in PK,
SeriesID int FK,
SerieSeasons int,
SerieEpisodes int)
```

EDITED AS PER @ADyson's Comment

```
--MoviesParticipated
MoviesParticipated (
MoviesParticipationId int PK
ActorID int FK
MovieID varchar(50) FK)

--SeriesParticipated
SeriesParticipated (
SeriesParticipationId int PK
ActorID int FK
SeriesID varchar(50) FK)
```

Comment: But wil the SeasonsnEpisodes table  be able to specify the number of episodes per season? The table will only be able to tell me how many episodes and how many seasons it has in general right?

Comment: @DiogoTeixeira "But wil the SeasonsnEpisodes table be able to specify the number of episodes per season?" ....yes, see my first comment on the main question

Comment: This MoviesParticipated table design is poor because the primary key doesn't enforce any proper data integrity...it's just a random and meaningless identifier. A table representing a many-to-many relationship should generally have a compound key made up of all the foreign key IDs. This prevents duplicate entries from being made. In this case, that's impossible because MovieID and SeriesID are alternatives rather than things to be combined together. That should be a signal that two tables are required, not a signal to create a useless PK as a workaround.

Comment: Since, there can be multiple actors participating in the same Movie/Series, there are going to be multiple entries in the "MoviesParticipated" Table. @ADyson Can you suggest an alternative then

Comment: @siddharthsidhu I already did - "two tables". See also my comments on the main question, above. But my point isn't about multiple actors/entries...my point is that with your design you can't stop **duplicate** entries. e.g. you could associate Actor 3 with Movie 1 more than once, and the database would not prevent it, which it should since that is redundant information.

Comment: @siddharthsidhu A properly defined primary key would cause an error in that case. The issue here is that there is a) no combination of fields which could make a unique key and b) key fields cannot be NULL - which both MovieID and SeriesID would have to be in this case, because they are alternative options, not values to be used in combination. The correct solution here is to create a `MoviesParticipated` table with `MovieID` and `ActorID` (with both fields defined in a compound key), and also a similar but separate `SeriesParticipated` table with `SeriesID` and `ActorID`

Comment: @ADyson I've edited my answer based on your commeny

Comment: Now i have another problem. I did everything you told me, however, I cant add records to the tables because of the foreign keys

Comment: Have you inserted records in the master tables(Actor, Movies, Series) first and then you moved to inserting into the rest right?, which table are you trying to insert into?

Comment: @SiddharthDinesh I was trying to put in the main tables, but they had FKs too, so i deleted the ones that was referering to the main tables. Now i have another problem. For example, i want to put data into the main tables, but theres the ParticipationID column, I put a random value into those columns? if i dont i will have always be searching for the right value in the MoviesParticipated table? Basicly what im asking is what is the ParticipationID column in the main tables for?

Comment: @DiogoTeixeira That was my mistake, after I split the Participation table, I forgot to remove the Participation ID from the other two tables. I have edited my answer, removing the aforementioned columns and also have changed the Forign key and have added a Primary key in the SeriesnEpisodes Table. You can refer the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since the relationship between the tables *Series* and the table *Episode* is [1 to N]
you don't necessairly need a third table. Just add a Foreign Key to *Episode* that refers to the Primary Key of *Series*.

You should get something like this for *Series*:

```
  Series (
  SerieID int PK,
  SerieName varchar(50),
  SerieDescription text,
  SerieCategory varchar(50),
  SerieYear varchar(4));
```

And something like this for *Episode*

```
  Episodes (
  SerieID int PK,
  SeasonNumber int,
  EpisodeNumber int,
  EpisodeLength int,
  ...
  SeriesID FK)
```

As for the Series - Actor relationship you need a third table.